# Confused with ECS multi container when registering with multiple targets groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have 10 nodejs services/apps which are *interdependent* on each other, that I want to setup on my ECS cluster.

**Initial Approach** was to create a task definition add 10 containers to it and spin each container as a separate ECS service with one task each. Each service is attached to a target group and confronted by same ELB. So, now I have 10 ECS services(1 task each - total 10 tasks), 10 target groups, 1 ELB. Everything is working fine in the approach.

**New Approach** after reading about [registering multiple targets to a single ECS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html), I tried setting up a single service and attached multiple target groups to it (Max 5 limit - was expecting same as number of containers in the task definition). So now I have 1 ECS service(1 task - total 1 task), 5 target groups, 1 ELB. But my only 5 Nodejs app works.

My questions revolving around above two scenarios.

1. Is is incorrect to run multiple services with same task definition to load balance each container in the task definition?
2. how is the Fargate pricing affected when running 10 services(1 task each - total 10 task) vs 1 service (1 task)?
3. how to register more than 5 target groups to a single service ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is is incorrect to run multiple services with same task definition to load balance each container in the task definition?

No, but as you have found there is a limit to this. You can only do up to 5.

> how is the Fargate pricing affected when running 10 services(1 task each - total 10 task) vs 1 service (1 task)?

You pay for each Fargate instance (each task), based on the amount of RAM and CPU you allocate to that task. The number of containers running in that task is unrelated to the price. Please see [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/) on Fargate pricing.

> how to register more than 5 target groups to a single service ?

As far as I can tell, you can't. Five is currently a hard limit. Since you were previously running 10 separate tasks, you could get that down to two separate tasks, each with five containers.